# Reset ratingInput in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I want to use a rating Input in conjunction with the `shinyjs::reset()`function. Everthing works fine except the reset functionality. Any hints?

Here is my minimal example:

```
library(shiny)
devtools::install_github("stefanwilhelm/ShinyRatingInput")
library(ShinyRatingInput)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  ratingInput("movieRating", label="Rate this movie...", dataStop=5),
  htmlOutput("movieRatingout"),
  actionButton("resetbtn", "reset")
))

#the corresponding server.R
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$movieRatingout <- renderText({
    paste("The movie was rated ",input$movieRating)
  })

  observeEvent(input$resetbtn, {
    reset("movieRating")
  })

})


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Have a look at the code for `shinyjs::reset()` by typing `reset` at the console without parentheses. It has a set of `if` statements that look for known Shiny input types so it can deal with each correctly. It doesn't know about your `ratingInput` function. It looks like you might be able to get it to work if you write an `updateRatingInput` function. Not sure about setting the 'type' attribute, though.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not that simple - there's also code in the JavaScript to detect what type of input this is. I just took a look at that rating package and it seems like there are only a handful of people using it, but if it gets a bit more popular I'll add support for resetting it. Until then I recommend writing your own custom code to reset it

Comment: Ok, I see, thank's!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create reset action manualy

1) Add js to reset icons ( set width of foreground ==0)

`jsCode <-"shinyjs.reset_1 = function(params){$('.rating-symbol-foreground').css('width', params);}"`

2) add this js to app using `extendShinyjs`

3) add `session$sendInputMessage` to reset input ( set `value == NULL`)

## Working example

```
jsCode <-"shinyjs.reset_1 = function(params){$('.rating-symbol-foreground').css('width', params);}"
ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  extendShinyjs(text = jsCode),
  ratingInput("movieRating", label="Rate this movie...", dataStop=5),
    htmlOutput("movieRatingout"),
  actionButton("resetbtn", "reset")
))

#the corresponding server.R
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$movieRatingout <- renderText({
    paste("The movie was rated ",input$movieRating)
  })

  observeEvent(input$resetbtn, {
    session$sendInputMessage("movieRating", list(value = NULL))
    js$reset_1(0)

  })

})
```